# Not all Cases visible when accessed from Contact related list

Tags: contact, case-object

When a contact record for 'Person A' is opened, we scroll down to 'Cases' related list and then click 'Go to List(17)' which displays 17 cases where Person A is set as Contact. However, this doesn't display all the cases (more than 17) where Person A is set as contact.

Is this an expected behavior? Can the page be set to display all the cases (even if it's in multiple pages) where Person A has been set as Contact?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Functionality is tied to Role settings as well as related record ownership.  Are you reviewing this list as an Admin with rights to all data?

Comment: @HomerJ Thanks for looking into this. Yes, looking into the related list as system admin but still not all the cases are being displayed.